# Outputting the contents of an editText to an array to be displayed in a textView

Tags: java, android, textview

I am having trouble with outputting data from my editText into a textView. My application asks for an input from the user and then displays it by concatenating them together with other words and displayed in one String in a textView at the end, although for testing purposes I have made the textView visible at all timed. The next word is asked for by using a button. The problem is that I am only able to display one element of the array at a time. For example if I enter the word "table" into my editText and then press the button. The textView will show "there is a table that is ". Once i enter another word such as "yellow" and press the button it shows "there is a  that is yellow"

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int i = -1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chooseGame();

    }

    public String enterWord() {


        String[] array = {"Adjective", "Adjective", "Proper Noun", "Name"};
        String entry;
        if (array[i].equals("Adjective")) {

            entry = "Enter an ";
        } else {
            entry = "Enter a ";
        }
        return entry;

    }


    public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the cnclick of the button


        i++;
        getNextWord();

    getInputs();



    }



    public void getNextWord() {
        String[] array = {"Adjective", "Adjective", "Proper Noun", "Name"};
        TextView wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
        Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.enterEditText);
        String displayText = enterWord() + array[i];
        String displayHint = array[i];

        wordTextView.setText(displayText);
        editTextView.setHint(displayHint);


        }

    }

    public void chooseGame() {


        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final TextView wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
        final EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.enterEditText);
        final Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);


        ArrayList<String> gamesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        gamesArrayList.add("A Vegan's Worst Nightmare");
        gamesArrayList.add("The Wet Floor Sign");
        gamesArrayList.add("The Meaning of life");
        gamesArrayList.add("Campfire Story");
        gamesArrayList.add("The Crocobearamouse");


        final ListView gamesListView = findViewById(R.id.gamesListView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                gamesArrayList);

        gamesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        gamesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                     if (position <= 5 && position >= 0) {

                                                         gamesListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                                         editTextView.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                                                         wordTextView.setVisibility((View.VISIBLE));
                                                         nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                                     }

                                                 }


                                             }
        );


    }

        public void getInputs() {
    TextView finalTextView = findViewById(R.id.finalTextView);
            EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.enterEditText);
            String[] inputsArray = {"","","","",""};
       inputsArray[i] = editTextView.getText().toString();
       String inputs = "There is a " + inputsArray[0] + " that is" + inputsArray[1];

        finalTextView.setText(inputs);


    }



    }
```

Here is my XML

```
  <TextView

        android:id="@+id/wordTextView"
        android:layout_width="418dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="Enter a noun"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Noun"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wordTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:onClick="nextWord"
        android:text="Next"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/enterEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/gamesListView"
        android:layout_width="404dp"
        android:layout_height="647dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="84dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalTextView"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enterEditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the getInputs() method, you are creating a new array every time, which clears the previously added values.

Move the following line outside of the getInputs() method, so that it will be available for the whole class (e.g. below the line int i = -1;)

```
String[] inputsArray = {"","","","",""};
```

This way you won't override the array every time, and it will show "there is a table that is yellow" instead of "there is a that is yellow".